# Error while performing Add Range

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have  this below LINQ query.

```
if (cts.Count > 0)
            {
                List<CT> ctList = new List<CT>();

                foreach (CT c in cts)
                {
                    var record = (from records in context.CTS
                                  where records.CTId == c.CTId
                                  select new Model.CT
                                  {
                                     CTId = records.CTId,
                                     Code = records.Code,
                                     ShortDescription = records.ShortDescription,
                                     LongDescription = records.LongDescription
                                  }).ToList();

                    ctList.AddRange(record);
                }
            }
```

**What I am trying to accomplish:**  I am going through each CT type object in cts List. Once I find record for each of those CTS objects I want to update ctList so at last we end up with records of different CTS. Right now I am getting error on AddRange line. It says the below:

`Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.CT>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DAL.CT>'`

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: @SLaks I understand the error that I am trying to assign DAL record to List CT?? Do i need to do some other type of conversion before I perform AddRange ?

Comment: You have two `CT` types, one `DAL.CT` and one `Model.CT`. These are not the same type, hence the error. Perhaps you wanted your `ctList` type to be `List<Model.CT>` ?

Comment: wow whats with downvote ? I could not solve this on my own so I came here

Comment: Note that `Model.CT` and `DAL.CT`  are considered distinct (and incapatible) types --*even it defined identically*

Comment: I am going to add a method called MapEntity to map DAL to Model. Thanks guys it was right infront of me and I didnt see it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion guys. It pointed me to right direction. I have added a method called MapEntity which maps DAL to Model. This error has cleared for me.